# Missing Values in Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am reading through some books regarding Bayesian Networks, I have been out of the loop in my probability basics, but I can't for the life of me understand how having

```
P(+A) = 0.2 and P(-A) = 0.8
```

I have in this (other example) table

```
P(+c |+A) = 0.85
P(-c |+A) = 0.15

P(+c |-A) = 0.333
P(-c |-A) = 0.667
```

I can't find how to get the value of -c and +c given only A. I know this is some basic stuff, I have been following different tutorials online,I even bought a couple of books to properly understand this, but I am having a harder time than normal grasping the basics of this. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: You will also want in your notation $P(+C \mid -A)$ or equivalently $1-P(-C \mid -A)$ if you want to find the marginal probability $P(+C)=P(+C \mid +A)P(+A)+ P(+C \mid -A)P(-A)$

Comment: @Henry correct, I added those terms as well for completion, thought I had added them, probably forgot out of sheer frustration.

Comment: So now you can find $P(+C)$ and similarly $P(-C)$

Comment: @Henry I am probably doing something wrong then because when I plug in the corresponding values for +C I get 0.4364 and when I use that to check on the derivation of `P(+C|+A)` I get a different result from 0.85

Comment: You have $P(+C)= 0.4364$.  You could also find $P(+A \mid +C) = \frac{0.85\times 0.2}{0.4364} = 0.38955$ and then  $P(+C \mid +A) = \frac{0.38955 \times 0.4364}{0.2} = 0.85$, which is what you started with